# is it possible to multiply two vectors or matrix with vector in the following way in R?

Tags: r, vector, sum, matrix-multiplication

```
A = 1:5
B = 11:15
```

I know `A %*% B` would give, `AB = [205] i.e. 1*11+2*12+3*13+4*14+5*15 =205`
However, I want `AB` to be (without going through a loop, if possible) `= (1*11)^2+(2*12)^2+(3*13)^2+(4*14)+(5*15)^2=10979`

Follow-up: this solves the above problem `sum((A*B)^2)` as suggested by @Dason and @nicola.

Now what needs to be done in case A is a matrix i.e. `A =matrix(1:10,2,5)`
After playing around I found this works: `rowSums((A %*% diag(B))^2)`

Comment: Maybe `sum((A*B)^2)`?

Comment: On a side note... the notation you're using to write out what your data is clearly isn't R.  If you're asking a R question you should make the effort to make it easily reproducible from within R.

Comment: Agreed. I usually do that when asking a question but I missed that part for this question.

Comment: And you can still modify the question now, for the benefit of other people later. The reprex package might be useful to help you easily prepare a reproducible example: http://reprex.tidyverse.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there isn't an operator/function that does it directly it's easy enough to chain a few together to get what you want without looping.

```
sum((A*B)^2)
```

Comment: what needs to be changed in case A is a matrix i.e. A =matrix(1:10,2,5) @Dason

Comment: That depends on what B actually looks like and what you want to happen in that situation.  Your question doesn't give enough detail on how you would want to expand in the case that A and B aren't the same size.

Comment: B is a vector of weights and would be the same all the time while I need to expand A to a n by 5 matrix @Dason

Comment: @user2797174 Still isn't the full info needed.  But honestly just play around with it.  Try different combinations of `A*B` and `A*t(B)` and see which gives you the correct multiplication.  Then you can just square and sum like I do in my answer.